# How to get order id in custom block sales_order_create reorder

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, blocks

I have created one custom block in reorder page for scheduling reorder.
I am not getting orderid in the phtml file.

I have used this for but not working

```
$this->getId(), $this->getEntityId
```

and

```
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote')->getQuote();
```

How do i get orderid in phtml file ?

I have made block using block type adminhtml/sales_order_create_data.

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
    <reference name="items">
         <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create_data" name="reorder" template="reorder/schedule.phtml" after="items_grid"/>
     </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
```

How do i use my own block  "adminhtml/reorder" ?

Please help

Comment: what is the purpose of schedule reordering on create order page?

Comment: My requirement is : Customer mailed us that he want his order to reorder every two week interval. Also customer can mail between the interval period to update the previously  order cart , so updated order will be ordered from admin. So for this i have make a section in sales order create in admin. in this section , i have given the facility to schedule(like week or days period) the order for future. for this i am unable to fetch his order id. or you know any better way to this functionality than please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

you can't get the order id of a new order, but if the order is edited or reordered, you will get it by

`$this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');`

Comment: We have tried this previously.it is not working

Comment: not working on reordering or editing an order?

Comment: Not working in reordering page. in sales order view page, id is present in url not in sales order create page

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get the order id or details under the sales->order

```
        $_order = $this->getOrder(); 
        $order_id =  $_order->getId();
```

where $_order is auto handled the order form `$_order = $this->getOrder()` for which particular order you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously order id can only be found while editing or reordering an existing order. If the order id is not in the url by default, then you may need to rewrite/override the adminhtml sales order controller and update the actions like of reorder will changed to:

```
public function reorderAction()
{
    $this->_initSession();
    $this->_getSession()->clear();
    $orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
    if (!Mage::helper('sales/reorder')->canReorder($order)) {
        return $this->_forward('noRoute');
    }

    if ($order->getId()) {
        $order->setReordered(true);
        $this->_getSession()->setUseOldShippingMethod(true);
        $this->_getOrderCreateModel()->initFromOrder($order);

        $this->_redirect('*/*',array('order_id',$this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id'))); // this is the line where we forward the order id to create new order page.
    }
    else {
        $this->_redirect('*/sales_order/');
    }
}
```

If you are creating a new order from backend, you will get the order id once order is placed.